# After apportable conversion: This item is not compatible with your device

Tags: android, google-play, apportable

I'm used www.apportable.com tool(Free version) to convert my Cocos2d IOS project to Android APK file. Conversion was successful after little tweak in code. Tested on my Nexus 7 - works. Uploaded on Google Play(in APK section is compatible with Nexus 7), now  can't install it from Google Play receiving following message:

> Asus Nexus 7 This item is not compatible with your device.

Any suggestions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:sharedUserId="com.estoty.SpaceThimblesHD" android:versionCode="1370237775" android:versionName="1.9" android:installLocation="auto" package="com.estoty.SpaceThimblesHD"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" />
    <application android:theme="@style/FullScreenActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:name="com.apportable.app.VerdeApplication" android:hasCode="true" android:debuggable="false" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:largeHeap="false">
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.libs" android:value="v cxx System objc ffi pthread_workqueue dispatch Foundation BridgeKit OpenAL verde" />
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="verde" />
        <meta-data android:name="android.app_name" android:value="Space Cups HD" />       
        <meta-data android:name="apportable.splash_screen_type" android:value="letterbox" />
        <meta-data android:name="apportable.orientation" android:value="landscape" />
        <meta-data android:name="apportable.opengles.fast_color" android:value="true" />
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.apportable.activity.VerdeActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="locale|mcc|mnc|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.apportable.iap.BillingService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.apportable.iap.BillingReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY" />
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE" />
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: just give a check in your manifest you migt not have mentioned that screen size devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the line:

```
    <supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc" />
```

caused by regression in the SDK when we recently added software pvr support. It will be fixed in the next SDK revision.

In the meantime, you can build a correct AndroidManifest.xml by editing .apportable/SDK/site_scons/android/mainifest.py as follows:

```
    diff --git a/site_scons/android/manifest.py b/site_scons/android/manifest.py
index 7b87747..2731546 100644
--- a/site_scons/android/manifest.py
+++ b/site_scons/android/manifest.py
@@ -68,9 +68,7 @@ def GenerateManifest(env, target):
     manifest += '          android:versionCode="' + Option(env, 'VERSION_CODE') + '"\n'
     manifest += '          android:versionName="' + Option(env, 'SHORT_VERSION') + '">\n'

-    if env['TARGET_TEXTURE_FMT'] == 'pvr':
-        manifest += '    <supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc" />\n'
-    elif env['TARGET_TEXTURE_FMT'] == 'atc':
+    if env['TARGET_TEXTURE_FMT'] == 'atc':
         manifest += '    <supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture" />\n'
     elif env['TARGET_TEXTURE_FMT'] == 's3tc':
         manifest += '    <supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc" />\n'
```

and then rebuilding the app to regenerate AndroidManifest.xml