# Apportable conversion VerdeActivity error

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, porting, apportable

Hi all and thanks in advance,

i'm new with apportable and i'm trying to port my iOS app. I can build the app with no error but when i try to "load"(apportable load) or "debug" (apportable debug) on device or emulatior i recieve this message ".VerdeActivity class does not exists".

i have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892975/after-apportable-conversion-this-item-is-not-compatible-with-your-device?answertab=votes#tab-top) too but i'm having the same problem also after the modifications.

Can anyone help me?

Here is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="Lallo"
          android:sharedUserId="Lallo"
          android:installLocation="auto"
          android:versionCode="1373630001"
          android:versionName="1.1.1">
    <supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <supports-screens android:resizeable="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:smallScreens="false"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:name="com.apportable.app.VerdeApplication"
                 android:hasCode="true"
                 android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                 android:theme="@style/FullScreenActivity"
                 android:debuggable="true"
                 android:largeHeap="false"
                 android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.libs" android:value="v cxx System objc ffi pthread_workqueue dispatch Foundation BridgeKit OpenAL verde" />
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="verde" />
        <meta-data android:name="android.app_name" android:value="Lallo" />
        <meta-data android:name="apportable.splash_screen_type" android:value="letterbox" />
        <meta-data android:name="apportable.orientation" android:value="landscape" />
        <meta-data android:name="apportable.opengles2" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="apportable.opengles.fast_color" android:value="true" />
        <activity android:name="com.apportable.activity.VerdeActivity"
                  android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|screenLayout|fontScale|uiMode|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
                  android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="fb361458087289348"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.apportable.activity.GdbServerService"
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="Lallo.GdbServerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is the complete error message

```
3052 KB/s (33870847 bytes in 10.834s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/Lallo-debug.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]
Starting: Intent { cmp=Lallo/com.apportable.activity.VerdeActivity (has extras) }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {Lallo/com.apportable.activity.VerdeActivity} does not exist.
```

Comment: Do you have any error/warning earlier in the compilation?

Comment: Did the sample projects load ok for you?

Comment: didn't try the sample projects yet. and yes i have 2 warnings in the compilation but they are about a class called CCLabelFX downloaded from github.

Comment: Is that the complete error message?  It sounds like you have either an incorrect AndroidManifest.xml file (found in ~/.apportable/Build/android-armeabi-debug/<project_name>/), or an invalid final <project-name>-debug.apk, found in the same directory.  Your manifest should have a line that looks like '<activity android:name="com.apportable.activity.VerdeActivity"'.  Is that the case?

Comment: here is the manifest:

Comment: <activity android:name="com.apportable.activity.VerdeActivity"                  android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|screenLayout|fontScale|uiMode|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"

Comment: manifest file was too long so i posted only the line you need

Comment: If you need the complete manifest i can edit the question.

Comment: That line is correct.  It seems that you have an incomplete APK.  If you completely delete your ~/.apportable/Build directory and run "apportable load" again, does the issue go away?

Comment: no... the issue is the same

Comment: I edited the question with the complete error message

Comment: and this is a warning given sometimes when i build the app.

Library not found for z. Try adding this to the 'deps' array in the 'add_params' section of your configuration.json file. Check ~/.apportable/SDK/System

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your package name is just "Lallo". You need a package name with dots in there. Usually a fully qualified reverse DNS name of your company with the package name.

For example:

```
com.apportable.Spin
```

You can change this in your .approj/configuration.json file.

Hope that helps.

Comment: i have changed it with com.apportable.Lallo but the error is the same

Comment: now the first lines look like this:

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.apportable.Lallo"
          android:sharedUserId="com.apportable.Lallo"

Comment: Why is this listed as solved when your last comment indicates this is still not working?  I have this same issue today, myself.

Answer (score 0):

An alterative reason for this error:

When running apportable for the first time, it asks which version of OpenGS ES (ES1 or ES2).
If you answer this wrong then you will get this error.

In my case I didn't realise the game I was working on still had the old version of cocos2d in it - uses ES1.

Hope this helps somebody else.  I spent most of a day on this issue thinking there was an issue with my phone...